# Flutter: BottomNavigationBar file giving error for context

Tags: flutter

I have created a bottomnavigatiobar file and calling it wherever required.
So, that i need to manage single file.

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:DTG/global_var.dart';
import 'package:DTG/routes/router.gr.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavigationTabBarView extends StatelessWidget {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  Function onTabChange;
  bool dacType = false;
  int dtgAcType;
  BottomNavigationTabBarView(this._currentIndex, {this.onTabChange});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bottomNavigationTabBarView();
  }



  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    final dtgAcType = Glob().g_acType ?? 0;
    onTabChange(index);
    if (_currentIndex == 0) {
      if (dtgAcType == 1) {
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.thome,
        );
      } else {
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.dhome,
        );
      }
    } else if (_currentIndex == 1) {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.search,
      );
    } else if (_currentIndex == 2) {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.search,
      );
    } else {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.settings,
      );
    }
  }


  BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationTabBarView() {
    const iconSize = 25.0;
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
      selectedItemColor: Colors.pink[300],
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.5,
      onTap: onTabTapped,
       
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        /*BottomNavigationBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.notification_important),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),*/
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.notifications),
              new Positioned(
                right: 0,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: 12,
                    minHeight: 12,
                  ),
                  child: new Text(
                    (Glob().g_acType ?? 0).toString(), //'600',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 9,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason it is giving error on context. Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

e.g.

```
 ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
            Routes.settings,
          );
```

I am not sure how to resolve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: Pass `context` and move/inline `onTabTapped` to `onTap`

```
bottomNavigationTabBarView(context);
...
BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationTabBarView(BuildContext context)
...
onTap: (int index) {
        _currentIndex = index;
        final dtgAcType = Glob().g_acType ?? 0;
        onTabChange(index);
        if (_currentIndex == 0) {
```

code snippet of Solution 1

```
class BottomNavigationTabBarView extends StatelessWidget {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  Function onTabChange;
  bool dacType = false;
  int dtgAcType;
  BottomNavigationTabBarView(this._currentIndex, {this.onTabChange});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bottomNavigationTabBarView(context);
  }

  BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationTabBarView(BuildContext context) {
    const iconSize = 25.0;
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
      selectedItemColor: Colors.pink[300],
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.5,
      onTap: (int index) {
        _currentIndex = index;
        final dtgAcType = Glob().g_acType ?? 0;
        onTabChange(index);
        if (_currentIndex == 0) {
          if (dtgAcType == 1) {
            ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
              Routes.thome,
            );
          } else {
            ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
              Routes.dhome,
            );
          }
        } else if (_currentIndex == 1) {
          ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
            Routes.search,
          );
        } else if (_currentIndex == 2) {
          ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
            Routes.search,
          );
        } else {
          ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
            Routes.settings,
          );
        }
      },
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        /*BottomNavigationBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.notification_important),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),*/
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.notifications),
              new Positioned(
                right: 0,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: 12,
                    minHeight: 12,
                  ),
                  child: new Text(
                    (Glob().g_acType ?? 0).toString(), //'600',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 9,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Solution 2: Convert `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and no need to pass `context`

```
class BottomNavigationTabBarView extends StatefulWidget {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  Function onTabChange;

  BottomNavigationTabBarView(this._currentIndex, {this.onTabChange});

  @override
  _BottomNavigationTabBarViewState createState() => _BottomNavigationTabBarViewState();
}

class _BottomNavigationTabBarViewState extends State<BottomNavigationTabBarView> {
  bool dacType = false;

  int dtgAcType;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bottomNavigationTabBarView();
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    widget._currentIndex = index;
    final dtgAcType = Glob().g_acType ?? 0;
    widget.onTabChange(index);
    if (widget._currentIndex == 0) {
      if (dtgAcType == 1) {
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.thome,
        );
      } else {
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.dhome,
        );
      }
    } else if (widget._currentIndex == 1) {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.search,
      );
    } else if (widget._currentIndex == 2) {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.search,
      );
    } else {
      ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
        Routes.settings,
      );
    }
  }

  BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationTabBarView() {
    const iconSize = 25.0;
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: widget._currentIndex,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
      selectedItemColor: Colors.pink[300],
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.5,
      onTap: onTabTapped,

      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        /*BottomNavigationBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.notification_important),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),*/
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.notifications),
              new Positioned(
                right: 0,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: 12,
                    minHeight: 12,
                  ),
                  child: new Text(
                    (Glob().g_acType ?? 0).toString(), //'600',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 9,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. Let me go through with it. +1